# TemplateSyntaxError at /register/ Invalid block tag on line 20: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

This code was working before I added Crispy Forms. Whenever I reload /register, this error appears.

```
 {% extends "django_blog/base.html" %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% block
content %}

<div class="content-section">
    
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom-mb-4">Join Today</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="border-top pt-3">
        <small class="text-muted"
            >Already Have An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="#">Sign In</a>
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you pasted, I think your problem is a result of auto-formatting. Most HTML formatters don't recognize or respect the Jinja-[like] syntax used in Django.

In your first line:

```
 {% extends "django_blog/base.html" %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% block
content %}
```

the `{% block content %}` spans two lines, which would be valid if it was HTML, but it's not, it's Django syntax! Django thinks your tag is malformed when that happens.

Just push it manually back into one line:

```
 {% extends "django_blog/base.html" %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %} {% block content %}
```

How do I keep this from reoccuring every time I format my document? Add an element where you want the formatter to break instead. Choose something harmless like a [`<wbr />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) element.

```
 {% extends "django_blog/base.html" %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %}<wbr />
{% block content %}
```

Comment: {% extends "django_blog/base.html" %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %}<wbr />
{% block content %} this one worked! Thank you!

Comment: @jdotcwzy If his answer solved your problem please click the checkmark on his answer. It's under the arrows on the top left of his answer.